# Large data in Result in Toad - Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

Ran a script that fetched me several million records. The file is too large for Excel. Smaller size results are easy to export. I need to save this result so that I can pull it into MS Access.  Is it possible to save the file of several million records to Access or Excel?

Regards,

D.O.

Comment: You could import directly by ms-access  using an import based on ODBC ..

Comment: not to be negative nancy - but you already have it in a real database - why make that much data harder to work with by putting it in Access?

Comment: Why do you need these millions of rows in excel? What do you plan to do with them?

Answer (score 1):

You could import directly by ms-access using an import based on ODBC using extenal data tools

But remember that  MS_ACCES allow Database (.mdb)with max  file size    of 
2 GB total for all objects in the database (data, forms, reports, indices, macros, modules, etc.)

see this for MS-Access  maximun capacities  http://www.databasezone.com/techdocs/acclimit.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue at work, an external auditor has requested large data sets in excel format.

After running my query, I get the result in a data grid. The grid has a toolbar at the top, the third icon has a tool tip that says Export Dataset.

Clicking on it opens the Export Dataset dialog, that has an "Export format" drop-down that offers several options.

When I choose "Excel File", toad creates an .xls file and writes data in it. This works if the data set is less that 65,535 rows.

When I choose "Excel Instance", toad launches an instance of excel 2013, and I was able to export 3 million rows this way.